# Stop Snowflake CSV export converting some cells to dates

Tags: sql, excel, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sorry if questions has been asked, but I haven't been able to find a q/a.

Every week I run some data in Snowflake at work and export it to a CSV and send through to some people.
Some of the cells in the CSV are sizes of clothes like 3-4, 5-6 or 6-7.
When exporting to CSV, excel converts this to a date format, eg: April-4, June-5, July-6.

Is there any of stopping this from happening within Snowflake?
At the moment I've been concatenating a space at the start with the size
`(" " || size) as size`, but this throws off the formulas they have in their sheet, so they need to find and replace within excel and get rid of the space.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify what is going on.  If by ***exporting to a CSV*** you really mean that Snowflake is exporting a CSV file, and you see a conversion to a date when you **Open** the CSV file using Excel, one way of preventing that is to **Import** the CSV file into Excel (using either Power Query or the legacy import wizard) and designate the `Size` column as being of type text. Depending on your user sophistication, it may be that you should distribute a VBA macro to do that.  In Snowflake you may be able to pre-pend with some kind of string character `'` and still allow users to **Open** the csv

Comment: Exactly what you said first. Snowflake is exporting a CSV file, and is converting to a date when opening the CSV file using Excel. I've tried putting a ' before the size but it still appears in Excel and messes up their formulas. They can just use find and replace, but it's an annoying extra step. I will look into Power Query and Legacy Import Wizard as you mentioned.

Comment: Hey. Importing through PQ does work, and thank you very much for the suggestion! I was just hoping for something that could be done within Snowflake without the need of extra steps every time the CSV is downloaded. It just feels like unnecessary additional steps.

Comment: Once you have set up PQ, maybe just a matter of refreshing the query?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but whenever the data is re-run and a new csv is generated, wouldn't they have to keep going through the same process of importing each time?

Comment: If you've already set up the query, you can re-use it.  You just need to feed it the new file path, which you can do via a named range on the worksheet, or various other methods.

Comment: Ok thanks. So is there really no way to circumvent this within the SQL in Snowflake?

Comment: The limitation is how the csv file is processed by Excel.  Why not just distribute Excel files instead of csv files?  You could query the Snowflake database with Power Query at your end; construct the Excel file and distribute that.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess that's the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that if I export the file as to_excel rather than to_csv that the formatting stays as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating a single quote rather than a space e.g.

```
("’" || size) as size
```

Comment: I get an invalid identifier error if I do that

Comment: You made need to escape it or, alternatively, use the ascii representation of the character

Comment: Thanks. Not quite sure what you mean though.

Comment: Try something like: Char(39)||size

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and the character still appears in the CSV when I download it. So every time the file is downloaded, they would need to go into it, Find and Replace ' with nothing. It only takes a few seconds, but just feels like an inelegant and unnecessary extra step.